# Spring Batch complex custom ItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm newbie in spring batch and I can't determinate what pattern for reader I would need to use. I need to create the class `WSRequestClass` and send it to SOAP web service.

```
public class WSRequestClass{
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
    private String data3;
    private String data4;
    private List<ClassB> dataList;
}
```

To create `WSRequestClass` is necessary:

1. Read `data1` and `data2` from table A.
2. Read `data3` and `data4` from table B.
3. The `List<ClassB>` should be create from more complex flow. First I get data from query from table C, but the result of this query is a `List<ClassA>`. I need process each item of `List<ClassA>` and convert it to `ClassB`, where some attributes are calculated from `ClassA`. (Chunk pattern but without writer).

   ```
   public class ClassA {
       private Date date;
       private BigDecimal amount1;
       private BigDecimal amount2;
       private String data;

       //getters & setters
       ...
   }

   public class ClassB {
       private Date date;
       private BigDecimal amount1;
       private BigDecimal amount2;
       private BigDecimal amount3;
       private BigDecimal amount4;
       private String data1;
       private String data2;

       //getters & setters
       ...
   }
   ```

I have found multiple examples for simples chunk pattern and tasklets, but none follows this structure. This job use java configuration and JdbcTemplate for queries. The development of the web service call it's done, my only issue is that I have to read from multiple tables and read efficiently the list, transform each item to `ClassB` and set to `WsRequestClass`.

Please guide me with the pattern to use, because common `ItemReader`not work for me, and I don't know how implement the custom reader that allow me do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this wrong.  There is a pattern in batch processing called the driving query pattern.  In it, your reader reads essentially the keys for the objects.  You then use processors to fill in the additional information.  You can read more about this pattern in the Spring Batch documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders

Comment: Thanks! the link was very helpful to clarify the pattern to follow! the only obstacle I encounter is if I call a DAO in the processor for get the `dataList` of `WSRequestClass`, the return of DAO is a list of `ClassA` (I can't change this because it is a DAO that already exist and I have to use), then I will create a `ServiceImpl` that call the DAO and transform the `List<ClassA>` to `List<ClassB>`, but this implies loop over the entire list with a For statement. Is there any better way to do this by taking advantage of spring batch?.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Minella, I was about write a custom reader which reads from multiple tables !